# Sql-Query: Hiding letters after space in the output

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've got a problem and hope you can help me find a solution.

```
Name    Hours   title

Name1   12  #1 (Text) - text - text

Name2   13  #1545 (text) - text - text

Name5   19  #33558 (text) - text - text

Name6   36  #54123 (text) – text
```

This is an extract from following query:

```
SELECT name AS Name, Sum((Unix_Timestamp(end)-Unix_Timestamp(start))/3600) AS Hours, title 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY title;
```

Well, we've got a column with names, a column called Hours(how many hours did a name spend on sth.?) and a column called title(the title of sth.). The title of sth. includes #, a number and text.

Is it possible to only get the number of the title? Like:

```
Name     Hours   title
```

Name1     12  1 
Name2     13  1545 
Name5     19  33558 
Name6     36  54123

I'm stuck because the number length varies. I don't know whether there is a function just calling everything before the first space if the title contains a number.

I need it to compare the title with a csv-file.

Your help will be much appreciated.
Soloco

**EDIT**
There is always a space after #.
Edit2:My bad, # has to be eliminated 2.

Comment: Do you always have a space after the #<number> ?

Comment: yes, there is always a space after #<number>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enter code hereTry this -

```
select substring(<columnname>,0,charindex(' ', <columnname>)) from <tableName>
```

In your case, the query will be -

```
select substring(title,0,charindex(' ', title)) from myTable
```

This works only if you have spaces and other text follwing your `#<number>`

USE LOCATE instead of Charindex for mysql -

http://www.overclock.net/web-coding/450373-mysql-query-help.html

Comment: Hm, now I got following error message: #1305 - FUNCTION timetracker.charindex does not exist . But thanks for the hint, hope I can build it up.

Comment: Forgot to mention, this query works on MS-SQL SERVER 2005. You might have to get corresponding function for charindex in mysql. Have edited the answer above, check if that helps.

Comment: Well that solved my charindex problem. But the output is empty now. It only shows one empty cell below title. Any idea of what the problem is or how to solve it?

Comment: pls rate the answer if it was helpful.. On empty rows, not sure buddy. I am new to mysql. So probably u can check how Locate works.

Comment: Well, I actually can't rate, but I will accept the answer asap I solved my empty row problem. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a beautiful solution, but it fulfills my needs right now.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(title,2,5)
```

If you see any other possibility please post.